# GCM is sending but not receiving for newly registered devices

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in the GCM Section. we have thousands of devices registered in our database, but some of them are not receiving messages. The newly registered devices are not receiving messages. Below is the code I am using to send the GCM. Can anybody help to find out the issue?

```
 //++ Send GCM
    private string sendGCM(string apiKey, string message, IEnumerable<string> registrationIds)
    {
        if (apiKey == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("apiKey");
        }

        if (message == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
        }

        if (registrationIds == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("registrationIds");
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "key=" + apiKey;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        JArray ids = new JArray();
        foreach (var regId in registrationIds)
        {
            ids.Add(regId);
        }

        jo["registration_ids"] = ids;
        JObject data = new JObject();
        //data["message"] = edtMessage.Text;
        data["message"] = message;
        jo["data"] = data;

        string query = jo.ToString();
        byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);

        Stream stream1 = request.GetRequestStream();
        MemoryStream mstream1 = new MemoryStream(buff);
        mstream1.CopyTo(stream1);

        stream1.Close();

        Stream stream2 = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        MemoryStream mstream2 = new MemoryStream();
        stream2.CopyTo(mstream2);

        String responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mstream2.GetBuffer());
        return responseString;
    }

                objGCM = new clsGCM();
                Int64 intGCMID = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);
                objGCM.execGetInfo(intGCMID);
                string strMessage = objGCM.InfoMessage;

                if (strMessage != null && strMessage != "")
                {

                    //++ Send to the devices
                    objDeviceInfo = new clsDeviceInfo();
                    DataTable dtDeviceInfo = objDeviceInfo.Load();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtDeviceInfo.Rows.Count; i = i + 1000)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<string> strDeviceToken = from g in dtDeviceInfo.AsEnumerable().Where(w => w.Field<Int32>("DeviceID") > i).Take(1000)
                                                             select g.Field<string>("DeviceToken");
                        sendGCM("Myapikeyhere", strMessage, strDeviceToken);
                    }

                    //++ Mark as sent
                    objGCM.execUpdateStatus(intGCMID);
                }
                Response.Redirect("~/Forms/frmGCM.aspx", false);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me a solution to overcome this?